# edit link menu in joomla (cant edit it)

Tags: joomla

Hi I'm new to joomla and I want to edit the link only in my menu top nav.

I already found the Menu and my problem is how will I be able to edit the link?

I found the link but it seems the link is disabled. I'm about to edit/updated the link only.

Here is my screenshot below
[image]

Can someone help me figured this thing out?
Any help is much appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You have to enter an external URL you have to do it this way as shown in image. Click on select and then system->External URL and then give any link you wish.[image]

Comment: ill check this one now

Answer (score 0):

Rather than editing the Link field directly, you need to choose a Menu Item Type (if different from the current menu type) and depending on the menu type, then choose an item or perform another action such as selecting the appropriate item in the parameters section at the right hand side of the page.